# Wordpress & Fastcgi proper setup?

Tags: php, cache, nginx

I'm trying to setup my sites to run with fastcgi_cache and found it a bit problematic that it doesnt really refresh content when something new is added to my site/webshop.

So i stumbled upon the plugin nginx_helper, and it seemed to be everything i needed - but is this the way to go? or should i look at something diffrent?
It requires a module to be installed on my server, and i have had a hard time getting it to work correctly on my AWS server

Answer (score 0):

clearing up external caches is hard, probably the best way to handle it is to set the cache expiry time to the longest time period in which you can afford to show "stale" information, and let the caches expire by themselves. (and hopefully you do not cache admin sessions....)